# What does "in" mean in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I've seen the word "in" multiple times in SwiftUI, but don't quite understand what it means. Because the word is so short and common, I'm having a hard time searching for its meaning and usage.

Most recently, I've seen it in the [onChange method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/onchange(of:perform:)) for example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var name = ""

    var body: some View {
        TextField("Enter your name:", text: $name)
            .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
            .onChange(of: name) { newValue in
                print("Name changed to \(name)!")
            }
 }
```

Comment: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html

Comment: `in` for the parameter going `in`to the closure.

Comment: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html#ID95 and esp. "closure expression syntax"

Comment: You are not alone in asking this https://forums.swift.org/t/history-why-does-closure-syntax-use-the-keyword-in/21885

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As like in your code example using `in` afther `newValue` let`s Swift and you know the return value of process is going happen on `newValue` so it is more like a symbol or flag called: **"token"** to you and to CPU that work is going happen on `newValue` because you put it before `in`, for example you gave `name` to **onChange** modifier with using `newValue in`, you will get updated value for `name` if get any new update, also note you can use `$0` instead of `newValue in` and works same.

---

```
.onChange(of: name) { newValue in
    return print("Name changed to \(name)!")
}
```

---

Or:

```
.onChange(of: name) { 
    print("Name changed to \($0)!")
}
```

---

Both are the same it depends how you like it.

Another example for better understanding:

```
let arrayOfInt: [Int] = [1, 2, 3]
```

---

```
let arrayOfString: [String] = arrayOfInt.map({ value in return value.description })
let arrayOfString: [String] = arrayOfInt.map({ $0.description })
```

For example we have an `arrayOfInt` and we want create a String array of it, for this work we can use `map`, and again like last example we used `in` in 2 way. in the first one as: `value in` and in the second on as `$0`. I recommend you work and learn more about **closure** in Swift/SwiftUI they are very important, without knowing them well, we cannot have good understanding of codes in iOS.

Also do not forget to attention to word of `return` right after `in` you can type and use or not use it, Swift is Smart enough to understand because of inference, but if you use it, it make your code much more easy and simple to read and better in syntax of code.

Comment: "to CPU that work is going happen on newValue" The CPU (at run time) has absolutely no knowledge of caring about the word `in`. It's just a piece of syntax, no different from why we use `:` before a type annotation, `=` for assignment, or how white space is largely ignored.

Comment: thanks, also I mentioned that it is like a symbol or flag.

Comment: The correct term is "token" or "lexeme"

Comment: noted thanks for info, and updated!